# How to get SSSP actual path by apache spark graphX?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have ran the single source shortest path (SSSP) example on spark site as follows:

[graphx-SSSP pregel example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#pregel-api)

Code(scala):

```
object Pregel_SSSP {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Allen Pregel Test", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), SparkContext.jarOfClass(this.getClass))
// A graph with edge attributes containing distances
val graph: Graph[Int, Double] =
  GraphGenerators.logNormalGraph(sc, numVertices = 5).mapEdges(e => e.attr.toDouble)
graph.edges.foreach(println)
val sourceId: VertexId = 0 // The ultimate source

// Initialize the graph such that all vertices except the root have distance infinity.
val initialGraph = graph.mapVertices((id, _) => if (id == sourceId) 0.0 else Double.PositiveInfinity)

val sssp = initialGraph.pregel(Double.PositiveInfinity, Int.MaxValue, EdgeDirection.Out)(

  // Vertex Program
  (id, dist, newDist) => math.min(dist, newDist),

  // Send Message
  triplet => {
    if (triplet.srcAttr + triplet.attr < triplet.dstAttr) {
      Iterator((triplet.dstId, triplet.srcAttr + triplet.attr))
    } else {
      Iterator.empty
    }
  },
  //Merge Message
  (a, b) => math.min(a, b))
println(sssp.vertices.collect.mkString("\n"))
 } 
}
```

sourceId: 0
Get the result:
(0,0.0)
(4,2.0)
(2,1.0)
(3,1.0)
(1,2.0)

But I need actual path like as follows:
=> 
0 -> 0,0
0 -> 2,1
0 -> 3,1
0 -> 2 -> 4,2
0 -> 3 -> 1,2

> How to get SSSP actual path by spark graphX? 
>   anybody give me some hint? 
>   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

You have to modify algorithm in order to store not only shortest path length but also actual path.
So instead of storing `Double` as property of vertex you should store tuple: `(Double, List[VertexId])`
Maybe this code can be useful for you.

```
object Pregel_SSSP {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Allen Pregel Test", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), SparkContext.jarOfClass(this.getClass))
    // A graph with edge attributes containing distances
    val graph: Graph[Int, Double] =
      GraphGenerators.logNormalGraph(sc, numVertices = 5).mapEdges(e => e.attr.toDouble)
    graph.edges.foreach(println)
    val sourceId: VertexId = 0 // The ultimate source

    // Initialize the graph such that all vertices except the root have distance infinity.
    val initialGraph : Graph[(Double, List[VertexId]), Double] = graph.mapVertices((id, _) => if (id == sourceId) (0.0, List[VertexId](sourceId)) else (Double.PositiveInfinity, List[VertexId]()))

    val sssp = initialGraph.pregel((Double.PositiveInfinity, List[VertexId]()), Int.MaxValue, EdgeDirection.Out)(

      // Vertex Program
      (id, dist, newDist) => if (dist._1 < newDist._1) dist else newDist, 

      // Send Message
      triplet => {
        if (triplet.srcAttr._1 < triplet.dstAttr._1 - triplet.attr ) {
          Iterator((triplet.dstId, (triplet.srcAttr._1 + triplet.attr , triplet.srcAttr._2 :+ triplet.dstId)))
        } else {
          Iterator.empty
        }
      },
      //Merge Message
      (a, b) => if (a._1 < b._1) a else b)
    println(sssp.vertices.collect.mkString("\n"))
  }
}
```

Comment: In the above code, what I tried was working fine for shortest path from source node to all nodes. But, is it possible to modify above code to get the shortest path between a single source node and a single destination node? I don't want to filter the output.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is outdated answer, but take a look at this solution [Find all paths in graph using Apache Spark](http://aponkin.blogspot.ru/2015/08/finding-all-paths-in-graph-using-apache.html)