# Spark Graphx shortest paths and print the vertexs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have generate a  graph G in Spark GraphX using Scala. I would like to find the number of edges that should be crossed starting from a known vertex pointA to arrive in another vertex pointB. In other words, I need the some shortest paths  and display the points from the vertex pointA to the vertex pointB calculated in number of edges (not using the edges' weights).

I am new to spark and scala , and i am struggling about these problems. is any possible that i can use the pregel to do that , pls let me know ! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your problem exactly? There are many GraphX SSSP solutions on the internet, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700124/how-to-get-sssp-actual-path-by-apache-spark-graphx , and it is not hard to write your own.
As for weigths -- well, you can always map them to 1.

Comment: i am new to scala, and the question is like this,find possible routes between point0 and point 3,and print them like this:  0->2->3;  0->4->5->3;  0->3;  0->4->8->9->3; please let me know